# UIView scaling between iOS devices

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I'm fairly new to using the auto layout in the storyboard, so I was wondering if I could get some help as to why my UIViews seem to be scaling to many times the width they should be on iPhone 6/6+.

The first image is the simulator for 5s, second is for 6. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6vyT.jpg

Comment: if you dont set constraints to your views, it will be mis aligned for different device types. I assume, you designed the storyboard for the iphone 5 layout and not with the wAny hAny configuiration

Comment: Yeah, I've continued playing around with it and it seems like that was the problem. I was so bogged down in constraints that I couldn't even tell what I was doing.

Comment: always give 4 constraints to your views. excpet the height and width give the other constraints